# How to bind Window Action Key + Middle click to Lower window in Ubuntu 19.10 (Gnome 3.34)?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 19.10

By default the combination opens the unhelpful window menu in Ubuntu 19.10/Gnome 3.34. I'd very much prefer the old behaviour. (While I appreciate the effort, please don't bother with advice that has to do with window title bars.)

Answer (score 0):

[GNOME Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Tweaks) give you the ability to change that. Start with

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

If not already installed.

Launch the GNOME Tweak Tool

Pick **Windows**  from the left side list.

Look for **Modifier to use for modified window click actions**

Change from <kbd>Super</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: I think that option is called "Window Action Key", at least in Tweaks that ships with 19.10. I have it set to Alt, and dragging and resizing work fine; however, middle click behaviour is not what I want.

Comment: OK, then would you please specify what you want, with regard to middle-click behaviour, by clicking [edit] and modifying your question so it is clear what you are asking for?